# MVC3 - Call logon method from GET request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I need to be able to call the built-in [HttpPost] Logon method (in the Account Controller) from a GET request. Basically, a new account would be assigned a temporary password, delivered via email. The user clicks on the link  in the email (containing a userid and temp pw in the URL), which would be handled in the account controller in the MVC app. I'm not sure how to handle this. Is it possible to redirect from a GET action method on the controller, to the POST logon action method? How would this be done while maintaining the HttpContext object? It seems that this wouldn't be doable outside of just creating a new GET logon method with the user and pw strings params and recreating the logic (using MembershipServer and FormsService objects) that's in the POST method.

**EDIT:** For anyone following this post, the solution I wound up implementing is:

- Using @Shyju's recommendation in a comment, I created a new GET action method to respond to the email link, that returns a "Register New User" view containing hidden inputs for the passed user\pw and a submit button.
- The view posts back to the normal logon method. If the user or pw has not been altered, the user will be authenticated
- I added a global action filter that tests for the user object property "MustChangePassword". If true, it redirects to the change password action method. This will happen for any method of any controller, except the account controller (so you can actually hit the logon, chg pw, and other methods)
- Then in the "ChangePassword" POST method, a successful pw change will reset the "MustChangePassword" property to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique string (use Guid) for each user and send that as the query string for the link in the email. In the GET action validate that against the user table & Temporary Password table and get the user record and consider that user as logged in user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually, the mechanism for generating the temp password, sending the email, authenticating and identifying the user as new, is already in place, via a web service. The issue here is that I'd like to use the exiting POST Logon action method, where the guts of authentication live. I plan to use the existing authentication with a flag for a new user to change the password. If there is no way to call the POST action method from a GET action method, I'll probably need to pull out the auth code to a private method and call it from both the POST and GET action methods.

Comment: Are you going to show  a view to the user ? If yes, you can do a POST from jQuery ajax from a view rendered from a GET Action

Comment: Hmmm... actually, that's not a bad idea! Throw up a "welcome new user page" with a "click here to join" button that posts back with the required info to the POST method. I wonder if there would be any security concerns shipping that temp pw to the client, only to send it back? Anyway, I like your idea. Why don't you copy your last comment to an answer so I can choose it as the accepted answer. And thanks again!